# Controling GPIO

Tags: gpio

I want to use GPIO to switch on/ off other aux items ( as 2 row LCD pannel, Relay switch ).
since I don't find a specific function in GPIOZERO module in Python just to switch on/off - is it OK to use Led's function?

for example- on gpio(17) a relay is conneceted, which i want to control it.
I use

```
`rel_sw=gpiozero.LED(17)`
```

`rel_sw.on()`, `rel_sw.off()`

is this the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will (or there certainly should) be a simple method to switch a GPIO on and off.  The LED method probably comes with additional baggage to set PWM on the GPIO and blink etc.

Have a look at [OutputDevice](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#gpiozero.OutputDevice).

Comment: great link that summerizes all. cheerz